# Prove that $|$ det $g| v(U)$ is the volume of $g(U)$ for any linear transformation $g: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

This is question of spivak's Calculus of Manifolds;

(a) Let $g: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a linear transformation of one of the fol­lowing types :
￼$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}\\ g(e_i) = e_i,  i\neq j\\ g(e_j) = a e_j \end{array}
\right. 
$$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}\\g(e_i)= e_i, i \neq j\\ g(e_j)=e_j+e_k\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}\\g(e_k)=e_k, k \neq i,j\\ g(e_i) = e_j\\
g(e_j) = e_i \end{array}
\right. 
$$
If $U$ is a rectangle, show  that the volume of $g(U)$ is $|$det $ g| · v(U)$.

(b) Prove that $|$ det $g| v(U)$ is the volume of $g(U)$ for any linear transformation $g: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$.

I am not getting any clue how to prove any part of this for b) I think any linear transformation can be written by composition of linear transformations of the type considered in a). But how to write this as a composition is also a question?

Comment: If $g$ is linear is can be written as $g_n \circ \cdots \circ g_1$, where the $g_k$ are elementary operations as in (a). You have $v(g_1(U)) = |\det g_1| v(U)$, $v((g_2 \circ g_1)(U)) = |\det g_2| v(g_1(U)) = |\det g_2| |\det g_1| v(U)$,  etc. Since $\det g = \Pi_k \det g_k$ you have the desired result.

Comment: But why $g$ is the composition of elementary maps how do I write explicitly?? This is a question...  Again I also don't know how to prove part a)...

Comment: I think as $g$ is linear so the corresponding matrix of it can be written as multiplication of elementary ones. This is my intution but I can't write it completely..

Comment: One way is to use reduced row echelon form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). For (a), the operations are essentially two dimensional operations, so I would suggest drawing a picture for each case and noting the congruent areas.

Comment: @copper.hat will you please give me answer writting descriptively . I am not getting your point by this...

Comment: @copper.hat Part (a) doesn't imply $v((g_2 \circ g_1)(U)) = |\det g_2| v(g_1(U))$ directly because we don't know if $g_1(U)$ is a rectangle.

Comment: @DoughnutPump: That is correct, a better approach would be to show that if $T$ is a triangle then $g(T)$ is a triangle, and show the above for triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for the first part of (a).

Let $U = \prod_{k=1}^n [c_k, d_k] $. Note that $v(U) = \prod_{k=1}^n |c_k -d_k|$.

Then $g(U) = [c_1,d_1] \times \cdots \times [a c_j, a d_j] \times \cdots [c_n,d_n]$ (adjusted appropriately for the corner cases, and note that $a$ may be negative). Then it should be clear that $v(g(U)) = |a|v(U) = |\det g|v(U)$.

The third part of (a) is equally straightforward.

The second part of (a) needs to look at how the $[c_j, d_j] \times [c_k, d_k]$ (adjusted appropriately for order) is changed by $g$. In this case the
rectangle is mapped into two congruent triangles whose total area is the
same as the original rectangle.